# Deleting special characters

Tags: c#, special-characters

To delete a special character from a text field, eg {'~;}, is it faster to use Regular Expression or to create a logic program?

Comment: depends on what you want to delete it from, a short sting, or a document that contains 1.4million characters.

Comment: Please be more specific, for example with example "before" and "after" samples? Otherwise, I'm thinking `return someString.Replace("~","");`

Comment: Generally speaking i'd say logic is faster as a regular expression engine has to do much more to just deal with your specific case (as it has to work for all RegExs too).

Comment: In TextoBox, which is used for Research, where I make a database query.
Data in the table are no special characters.

Comment: In terms of faster to code, depends on your knowledge of regex, and how complex the logic would otherwise be.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure how to go about this, then you'll probably find it easier to use logic. On the other hand, you're likely to learn a lot more by using a Regex.

And as [Marc Gravell said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182001/deleting-special-characters#comment-10050639), your best bet may well be `String.Replace`